# Android Developer kotlin playground code error

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun birthdayGreeting(name: String): String {
val nameGreeting = "Happy Birthday, $name!"
val ageGreeting = "You are now 5 years old!"
return "$nameGreeting\n$ageGreeting"
}

No main method found in project.
```

Can someone explain how to solve this, I've just started taking this code labs. thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin needs a `main` function so that when you actually run it, it knows what to do.

```
fun main() {
    println(birthdayGreeting("John Doe"))
}

fun birthdayGreeting(name: String): String {
    val nameGreeting = "Happy Birthday, $name!"
    val ageGreeting = "You are now 5 years old!"
    return "$nameGreeting\n$ageGreeting"
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i got it now... it was a reading mistake...

Answer (score 0):

**Shan perera**, It is nice to see you here. Will explain.

When we usually run a program [piece of code]. The entry point, we call as `main()`.

[image]

This function

```
fun birthdayGreeting(name: String): String {
    val nameGreeting = "Happy Birthday, $name!"
    val ageGreeting = "You are now 5 years old!"
    return "$nameGreeting\n$ageGreeting"
}
```

it Looks good for printing 5 year old boy birthday wishes. well for executing this function we have to create a main() method. In Kotlin you must follow the syntax like this.

```
fun main() {
    println(birthdayGreeting("Arnold"))
}
```

We can write it as

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(birthdayGreeting("Arnold"))
}
```

Then defently it will print

Happy Birthday, Arnold!
You are now 5 years old!

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. the code i put here is from android developer codelab and i should check it with kotlin playground as it is, there it says the code should print an error saying "No value passed for parameter 'name'", so i try to modify "birthdayGreeting" replace with "main" function and then it prints "No main method found in project.", now i doubt that codelab is wrong somehow or....